# Adding Menu to a Window in GTK

Tags: gtk, rust

I want to add menu to the top of a window in gtk, a normal menu with File, View, Help, etc. In the gtk documentation at http://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/ there's no example of how to use Menu or MenuShell. How can I do that?

Comment: When in doubt, refer to [the original GTK+ documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/). You set your window's child to a GtkBox or GtkGrid and put a GtkMenuBar at the top. You can build this in glade too, and GtkAction/GtkUIManager for shortcuts. There's also the new GMenu/GAction system which allows you to define your menu layout in a .ui file and provide the menu options to other facilities like keyboard shortcuts and dbus just as seamlessly. The choice is yours.

Comment: @andlabs is definitely correct that the original documentation is the best place to go. The binding, if it exposes the original API clearly enough, should just make you able to follow the C API, seeing as bindings are going to tend to have lower-quality docs. The only time you should have to look at the binding docs are when it exposes something slightly differently or when you're still learning the basics of the binding.